# Strongly typing a view to a class from the webservice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Currently I use a webservice to call the database and pass back an object back to my MVC app. The purpose is to display the data on a table.

So would it better if I just type the View to the class from the webservice, or should it always be typed to a model inside the MVC app? If I type it to a model inside my app, then I would have to create a new instance of the class and copy all the information over, which seems like a waste of time.

Which one is considered best practice? Strongly typing to a class from the webservice or a class within the MVC app?

Cheers.

Comment: why do you even need a web service? why can't your controller call the model/database? you don't need web services for mvc apps, as controllers are capable of returning basically anything (html, xml, json, images, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to shield your application from external changes and your views from knowing the internals of the application. So I would just create a separate class and then map it to the web service class.  You can also use something like AutoMapper to do the mapping for you.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a dependency on the class from WebService. MVC's ViewModel is desined to be simple data representation. You can easely map your WebService class to ViewModel class using [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/). This is considered as best practice and described in [this book](http://www.manning.com/palermo2/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The best practice is to use a view model with no coupling to the domain model - a simple DtO. However, any validation applied to your domain needs to be replicated. So sometimes the trade-off is to pass domain entities to the view - and I'm very happy to do that.

In your case - go with the DTO as others on here suggest.